# 404 not found (API url not found even though it 100% exists)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular11

I'm trying to get a product by id. Now when I tried this with postman it worked perfectly fine no problems whatsoever. But, when I tried to get the data with Angular it didn't work it keeps saying 404 not found I don't know what's the problem. Please if anyone knows tell me. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my code.

**express.js:**

route:

```
router.get("/get-product/:id", async (req, res) => {
  await fetchProductById(req, res);
});
```

utils:

```
const fetchProductById = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const prod = await Product.findOne({_id: id});
  if (prod) {
    if (prod.length == 0)
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "No Products",
        success: true,
      });
    else {
      res.status(200).json({
        prod,
        success: true,
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({
      prod,
      message: "couldn't find any product",
      id: req.id,
      success: false,
    });
  }
};
```

**Angular:**

now the angular service:

```
getProductById(id: any){
        return this.http.get<Products[]>(
            environment.api + "products/get-product?id="+id
        )
    }
```

subscribing to the service inside a component:

```
    let id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this._product.getProductById(id).subscribe(
      (data: Products[])=>{
        console.log(data)
      },
      error =>  {
        console.log("there has been an error trying to fetch this product: "+id)
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a query parameter instead of an url parameter. It should be `"products/get-product/"+id`:

```js
getProductById(id: any){
        return this.http.get<Products[]>(
            environment.api + "products/get-product/"+id
        )
    }
```